# group series based in limited time periods with SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've got a table with user and date values. For every user there can be multiple date values. In the script below I insert the columns sincePrevious and sinceFirst during the select, per user based on another answer I've found at stackoverflow.

```
SELECT 
 a.user as 'user'
,a.date as 'date'
,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,b.date,a.date),0) as 'sincePrevious'
,datediff(day, min(a.date) over (partition by a.user), a.date) as 'sinceFirst'
FROM
(select  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date) as Rank from HUT_regels) as a
LEFT JOIN 
(select  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date) as Rank from HUT_regels) as b
ON a.user = b.user AND a.Rank = b.Rank + 1
ORDER by 'user', 'date'
```

What I want to do is insert another column in a similar fashion (during the select) which adds an unique group ID based on the user value, and the time difference between two rows. In the example I've added some groupIds. When the difference in dates between two sequential dates for the same user is larger than 50 days (in this example), this must be seen as a new 'sequence' of  occurences. groupIDs 2, 3 and 4 reflect this.

```
user      date        sincePrevious  sinceFirst  groupId
100000029 25-05-2012  0              0           1
100002161 08-01-2012  0              0           2
100002161 04-02-2012  27             27          2
100002161 15-02-2012  11             38          2
100002161 28-03-2012  42             80          2
100002161 23-05-2012  56             136         3
100002161 11-07-2012  49             185         3
100002161 29-08-2012  49             234         3
100002161 24-10-2012  56             290         4
100002161 21-11-2012  28             318         4
100005242 07-05-2013  0              0           5
100005242 10-05-2013  3              3           5
100005242 14-05-2013  4              7           5
100005242 17-05-2013  3              10          5
100005242 21-05-2013  4              14          5
100005242 24-05-2013  3              17          5
100005242 28-05-2013  4              21          5
100005242 07-06-2013  10             31          5
...
```

groupIds should be unique, but don't have to be consecutive or even numbers for that matter.

I know this is possible with a CTE, but would like to find a solution similar to the way sincePrevious and sinceFirst are generated.

My usecase is SQL Server, but a more universal solution (I mention MySQL, but PostgreSQL for instance would also be nice) could help others as well.

Comment: There is no universal solution when it involves CTE or Analytical functions since RDBMs handles it in different fashion and some does not even support it (like analytical functions in mysql is not)

Comment: I know, what I meant was like @Gordon-Linoff said a more ANSI-like solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using `lag()` and `min()` to get the values:

```
select r.*,
       datediff(day, lag(date) over (partition by user order by date), date) as sincePrevious,
       datediff(day, min(date) over (partition by user), date) as sinceFirst
from HUT_regels r;
```

To add `GroupId`, you just need a subquery and conditional aggregation:

```
select r.*,
       sum(case when sincePrevious < 0 then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by user order by date) as groupId
from (select r.*,
             datediff(day, lag(date) over (partition by user order by date), date) as sincePrevious,
             datediff(day, min(date) over (partition by user), date) as sinceFirst
      from HUT_regels r
     ) r;
```

This is all ANSI standard functionality.  However, it was not fully introduced in SQL Server until version 2012.  In earlier versions, you can use `apply` instead.

Comment: This isn't the answer I was looking for. With the second block of code, groupId increments by one each row (assuming properly sorted output) and resets with a new user.